# multiple piping in C shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, ipc

can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code. I'm able to write successfully to the pipe but not able to get the output when i use that pipe output side as an input for another command. Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>     //for pid_t fork() and other system calls
#include <signal.h>     //for signal()
#include <sys/types.h>


void command_EXECUTER(char *args[]);
void command_HANDLER(char *args[]);
int pipe_EXECUTER(char *args[], int in, int pos);

void shell_INIT(){

    int is_interactive = isatty(STDOUT_FILENO);

    if(is_interactive){



    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char **envp){

    char shell_INPUT[1024];
    char *tokens[256];
    int tok_counts = 0;

    while(1){

        memset(shell_INPUT,'\0',sizeof(shell_INPUT));

        printf("\n%s@%s: ",getenv("USER"),getenv("SESSION"));
        fgets(shell_INPUT,1024,stdin);

        if((tokens[0] = strtok(shell_INPUT," \n)\t")) == NULL) continue;

        tok_counts = 1;

        while((tokens[tok_counts] = strtok(NULL, " \n\t")) != NULL) tok_counts++;
        /*
        int i=0;
        while(tokens[i]){
            printf("%s ",tokens[i]);
            i++;
        }
        tokens[tok_counts] = NULL;*/
        command_HANDLER(tokens);

    }


    return 0;
}

int fileIO_EXECUTER(char *args[], int in, int pos){
    int fd;
    pid_t pid;

    if((pid=fork())==0){
        switch(pos){

            case 0: 
                    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    break;


        }
    }
}

int pipe_EXECUTER(char *args[], int in, int pos){

    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pipe(fd);

    if((pid=fork())==0){
        printf("%s %s %s %d\n",args[0],args[1],args[2],pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        switch(pos){

            case 0: dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);     //first command
                    //close(fd[1]);
                    break;

            case 1: dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);             //in between command
                    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    //close(fd[1]);
                    break;

            case 2: dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);         //last command
                    //close(fd[1]);
                    break;

            default: printf("wrong input variable\nexiting");
                     exit(1);   

        }
        if(execvp(args[0],args)==-1) printf("%s: command not found",args[0]); fflush(stdout); kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);

    }else if(pid<0){
        printf("couldn't create child");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        wait(pid);
    }

    return fd[0];

}

void command_EXECUTER(char *args[]){

    pid_t pid;

    if((pid=fork())<0){
        printf("couldn't create the child");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid==0){

        if((execvp(args[0],args))==-1) printf("%s: command not found",args[0]); fflush(stdout); kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);
    }
    else wait(pid);

}

void command_HANDLER(char *args[]){

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char spec_chars[100];

    while(args[i]){
        if((strcmp(args[i],">")==0) || (strcmp(args[i],"<")==0) || (strcmp(args[i],"|")==0) || (strcmp(args[i],"&")==0) || (strcmp(args[i],"$")==0)){
            spec_chars[j] = *args[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(j==0){
        if(strcmp(args[0],"exit")==0) exit(0);
        else if(strcmp(args[0],"clear")==0) system("clear");
        else command_EXECUTER(args);
    }
    else{

        int in = 0;
        int h = 0;
        int pos=0;
        char data[1024];
        int k=i;
        i = 0;
        while(args[i]){
            if(strcmp(args[i],"|")==0){
                args[i] = (char *)NULL;
                in = pipe_EXECUTER(args,in,pos);
                int n = read(in,data,sizeof(data));
                printf("%s %d\n",data,n);
                fflush(stdout);
                args = args+i+1;

                //printf("%s something %s",args[0],args[1]);
                pos = 1;
                i=0;
            }else if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0){


            }else if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0){

            }else if(strcmp(args[i],"&")==0){

            }
            else{
                i++;
            }

        }
        in = pipe_EXECUTER(args,in,2);
    }

}
```

for eg if i use

> ls | sort

'in' descripter will have ls inside it but 
when that same output is accessed by 'sort' it hangs there ... or the child executing that command never die and due to this parent keeps waiting.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`); also test against failure (and use `perror` on failure of) every [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Consider also using `strace`  & `valgrind`

Comment: actually I have just started with this and have no knowledge of how to use gdb or other debugging tools .. if you could please help .. thanks

Comment: No, you need to learn `gdb`. It is a skill useful for many years! Read [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html)

Comment: hey, @BasileStarynkevitch i studied and tried with all gdb, strace and valgrind but still with no luck :(

Comment: Some bugs take weeks to get found. Good luck! Don't give up. Take some rest, and then continue hunting your bug. Don't forget to read the documentation of every syscall you are using. In particular, your use of `dup2` is wrong: you don't handle the failure of `dup2`. Also, call `fflush` before `fork`

Comment: Also, study the source code of existing free software shells (e.g. [fish](http://fishshell.com/), [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), etc...). And read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: if I didn't have time constraint, i would never have ask this question here, but still thanks for your advice and support :)

Answer (score 0):

> 'in' descripter will have ls inside it but when that same output is
>   accessed by 'sort' it hangs there

This is caused by the oversight of not closing the write end of the pipe *in the parent process*, because `sort` naturally waits until *all* file descriptors referring to the write end are closed, making sure that no more input will arrive. Thus, in `pipe_EXECUTER()` you have to call `close(fd[1])` before you `return fd[0];` and of course the debugging code

```
                int n = read(in,data,sizeof(data));
                printf("%s %d\n",data,n);
```

in `command_HANDLER()` has to be removed, to not consume the input for `sort`.